# Get table name of Redshift COPY commands from stl_load_commits

Tags: amazon-redshift

Trying to get a list of COPY commands run on a particular date and the tables that were updated for each COPY command.

Working with this query:

```
select
        slc.query as query_id, 
        trim(slc.filename) as file, 
        slc.curtime as updated, 
        slc.lines_scanned as rows, 
        sq.querytxt as querytxt
from stl_load_commits slc
    join stl_query sq on sq.query = slc.query
where trunc(slc.curtime) = '2020-05-07';
```

How can we get the table that was updated for each COPY command? Maybe using a Redshift RegEx function on `querytxt`? Or joining to another system table to find the table id or name?

Comment: The table name would presumably be the second word in the query (after `COPY`), so you could try extracting that. Take a look at a few queries that performed the copy operations to see if you can find a consistent pattern.

Answer (score 0):

this regex will select the `table` or `schema.table` from `stl_query.querytxt`

```
select
        slc.query as query_id,
        trim(slc.filename) as file,
        slc.curtime as updated,
        slc.lines_scanned as rows,
        sq.querytxt as querytxt,
        REGEXP_REPLACE(LOWER(sq.querytxt), '^copy (analyze )?(\\S+).*$', '$2') AS t
from stl_load_commits slc
    join stl_query sq on sq.query = slc.query
where trunc(updated) = '2020-05-07';
```